# AirportExtreme network problems

Tags: macos, airport-extreme, airport-express

At my house I use a Mac, as do my kids, and we have an Airport Extreme that we use with many airport expresses throughout the house for Internet and music streaming. However, sometimes the network will slow down to a crawl, music will cut out, and sometimes our Internet will just keel over and die until we reboot the network.

My son is tech-savy as well, and he thinks  That there may be another network intersecting with ours and thereby occasionally "jamming" it. Normally his theories are false, and I eventually find a solution that works on my own. However this time, I can't figure it out, so my question is: is there something to my son's theory?  If so, what are my options?  If not, what can I do?

Comment: Have you tried switching to a different channel? Do you see your neighbors' wireless networks in the network list? How many are there? What channels are they on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by @Daniel Beck, a channel conflict is often an issue.  This app [iStumbler](http://www.istumbler.net/) can give you info on nearby access points.  Often the issue is that the AP is set to auto select a channel and so nearby APs may change channel from time to time.  I would run this app in several areas of the house on several days (especillay when you have an issue) and see if there is a conflict.  Then set your AP to use only one channel that is typically unused.  This has fixed a similar issue for me on several occasions.

Comment: Channels overlap. Sometimes it's still difficult to find a good channel.